# How should I move on after writing a fight scene and trying to introduce a new (but mentioned) character?

Tags: creative-writing, short-story

So I'm writing a short story for literature and I have come upon an odd spot in my story where I need to introduce a new character, but I got to end a fight scene first. I had been doing some research on writing scenes with physical/dialectical conflict, but I'm trying to end it so I can move on. Any suggestions? Help? If you need a sample of the scene, I'll gladly submit some

Comment: Asking what to write is off-topic here, have placed on hold.

Answer (score 2):

The basic question here is:

#### How do your write anything at all?

My answer is always the same:

## Write it. Read how it *feels*. Rewrite it.

The **fundament** for your novel, short story, play, comic, computer game, or whatever **is a story**. Each and every story has a rhythm. This is sometimes called plot, or story arc, or whatever. I like the term **rhythm**, because it implies that

- **a person who reads a lot will have developed a sense for that rhythm**

When you read a story (or watch a movie or whatever) you will *feel* whether the story flows like it should or feels awkward or confusing or bumpy.

So all you need to do to know how to write is to **write whatever comes to your mind** and then **read what you have written**. You will have a clear understanding of what you need to change.

If you don't have that feeling, you will need to write more, until you develop that story sense.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a rather simplistic answer but why not just knock this soon to be newly mentioned character out and move things on to him waking up? If there is going to be a fight, that's certainly not an unexpected outcome. It certainly allows for a quick switch to his perspective and to maybe explain this fight from his perspective. If that is the angle you are going for of course.